# grub problem with windows 7

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my computer, that was already running Windows7 perfectly fine.

- Windows is on `/dev/sda3` and Ubuntu on `/dev/sda6` - same HDD, but different partitions.

The problem is right now when i boot it goes into grub and i can choose:

1. ubuntu
2. memtest86
3. windows7

but when i click Windows7 it return to grub again. Please help me, i really need this working.

Comment: Have you tried running "sudo update-grub" in a terminal when logged in to Ubuntu? After running that, try again and see if there is any difference.

Comment: nah is the same

Comment: i got this Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2

Comment: above you stated windows is in partition sda 3 the "found" statement says it is in sda 2. The reason??????

Answer (score 1):

did you remove the loader for windows as i saw in many pre-configured windows 7 machines that it comes with partition for its boot loader and when you chose windows 7 from grub menu it will trigger the boot loader of windows. so the question is did you remove a small partition less than 100 MB which holds the windows loader or maybe there is something happened to it. if so then you got problem with windows and i quess this is the issue you can install the MBR for windows by using ubuntu live cd look here:
http://blogs.deepal.org/2009/06/how-to-fix-mbr-using-ubuntu-live-cd.html

but this i think will replace the grub and you will boot to windows directly so you will not be able to see the ubuntu and then you need to follow another solution to bring ubuntu back by following this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: i didnt remove nothing, on ubuntu 11.04 instalations it asked if i wanted to each time computer started to ask for with operating system to run, each ubuntu or windows, ubuntu did everything automatically, i didnt touch nothing about making any partitions

Comment: i will place here some pastebins maybe can help

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/601029/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/601023/

Answer (score 1):

i cant see really any problem in the grub 
try to install windows MBR and see if it will boot and then install grub as i mention in the old post maybe it will be fixed

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/601059/

Comment: ok just dont this

insert windows 7 or windows vista cd to repair, get on console prompt, write 

bootsec /fixboot and everything works nice :)

i keep grub and get windows 7 working :D

thanks for all help around

Comment: it looks as i said before windows loader problem not grub thats why i suggested to you to fix the windows boot loader